# Magento HTML in product name not working

Tags: php, html, magento, magento-1.9

I am working on Magento CE 1.9 in theme `rwd`
I have `<br>` tag in product names but still product names are rendered as single line.
I already set **Allow HTML Tags on Frontend** to **Yes** for `name` attribute from Manage attributes.
How I can convert `<br>` to new line character so that product name will be shown on 2 lines?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Make sure that you've changed the value for the correct store, ie. if you changed the default one check if frontend store where you check uses that default value.

Comment: Do you have caching enabled? If so, then refresh the cache and check again.
Also make sure you are changing the value for the correct store.

Comment: @Zefiryn: I tried it for all 3 scopes i.e. Global, Website as well as Store.
Setting **Allow HTML Tags on Frontend** to **Yes** for name attribute works on product view page but not in product listing.

Comment: @MahmoudTantawy: cache is disabled.. I also reindexed data for **Product Attributes** after attribute property changes..

Comment: If it works on product view page, then it should work on product list as well. Default rwd theme uses exactly the same code. Your only option is to go to `Mage_Catalog_Helper_Output` and debug `productAttribute`method to see why it is not working as expected on product list.

Comment: @Zefiryn: Thanks.. your approach helped... I have mentioned changes below..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am adding answer here because I was unable to properly display answer in comment.
@Zefiryn:
Tried answers above. But I followed approach suggested by you.
But I did not make any changes directly in core files, instead I copied `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Output.php` from `core` codepool to `app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Output.php` into `local` codepool. 
Changed following condition on `line number 125`

```
if ($attribute->getFrontendInput() != 'price') {
    $attributeHtml = $this->escapeHtml($attributeHtml);
}
```

TO

```
if ($attribute->getFrontendInput() != 'price') {
    if($attributeName != 'name') {
        $attributeHtml = $this->escapeHtml($attributeHtml);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix as follows:

**Category Page:**

> 1. Go to the folder/file: /rwd/catalog/product/list.phtml
> 2. Go to line number 54,

Change this code

```
 <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName() , 'name'); ?>
```

To

```
<?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, nl2br($_product->getName()) , 'name'); ?>
```

Problem does not exist in Product View Page. However, if this does pop up in Product Page then do the below.

**Product Detail Page:**

> 1. Go to the folder/file: /rwd/catalog/product/view.phtml
> 2. Go to line number 51,

Change this code

```
 <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName() , 'name'); ?>
```

To

```
<?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, nl2br($_product->getName()) , 'name'); ?>
```

Check and let me know if this works for you.

Happy to Help!

Happy Coding...

[Editing this answer]

Though the above solution is a FIX that can be considered, below is the thing that would fix it.

> 1. Complete CACHE clear by deleting the folders under /var/cache and /var/full_page_cache (Enterprise)
> 2. Run a complete Re-Index by executing the below command or by using System > Index Management

Command under folder /shell/:

> php indexer.php --reindexall

Comment: I tried with your solution. But it is converting `<br>` to `&lt;br&gt;`

Comment: Where is it converting? Does that show up somewhere in the frontend?
You can also try the function nl2br(); instead of htmlspecialchars();

Comment: I guess it is not advisable to modify core magento files, which rwd theme is part of.

Comment: @Shivani: Its showing up in frontend product listing. Also tried with nl2br(), no success.. :( :(

Comment: @Mahmoud.. Agreed! That's the reason I mentioned quick fix. Ideal solution would be recreate this attribute (unless there are products which are live), otherwise create a new theme and do this code.

I have reviewed the Mage_Catalog_Helper_Output line number: 132 which checks for a condition, Allowed HTML and Enabled WYSIWYG editor- needs to be set to Yes (This check becomes valid for a TextArea/Editor field)

Comment: @chaitanya ... clear cache and run a re-index. That will make it work. It works in my machine like a charm.

Comment: @Shivani: tried with re-indexing.. same result even in base default theme.. still getting same result.. Works fine on product page (when **Allow HTML Tags on Frontend** is set to **Yes** for name attribute) but not on product listing page.. :(